# MySQL Function not running properly on server

Tags: mysql, function

I have a function that works on my local MySQL database but does not return the same value on the public server. I am not sure why. I am using UTF-8.
The parameter is an integer (`Keyval`). The idea is to take `Keyval: 216` and convert it to '‚‚„ƒˆ', where they are characters: 130,130,132,131,136 thru: `MakeAltAbbr(216)`

```
UPDATE `cc_team` SET `AltTMAbbr`= MakeAltAbbr(TeamKey) WHERE TeamKey = 216;
```

On localhost it creates some special characters, on the server it is 'blank'.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE cc CHAR(5);
    DECLARE str CHAR(5);
    DECLARE x INT default 0;
    DECLARE y INT default 0;
    SET str = '';
    SET x = 1;
    SET cc = LPAD(Keyval,5,'0');
    SET y = LENGTH(cc);

    WHILE x <= y DO
        SET str = CONCAT(str,CHAR(SUBSTRING(cc,x,1) + 130));
        SET x = x + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN str;
END
```

Comment: so what value is in `Keyval`?

Comment: So this function just takes the first 5 characters of Keyval and appends the same characters offset by 130? As @MarcB points out, this all depends on Keyval, which isn't declared here.

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify things... anybody?